# Seperate path from file name pyqt5

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5

So basically I am trying to make a program like photoshop. The thing I am trying to do right now is have a person click a a open file button and then choose their file from the file explorer and open it in the editor in a QLabel and store the name of it in a QListWidget next to it. The thing is that I have done everything make the button open the file explorer and add the picture to the label through a pixmap now I want to make it so when I click on the name of the file in the QlistWidget the picture pops up in the pixmap however I have encountered two problems first of all when when I add the filename to the QlistWidget it adds the filepath not the name. I have tried almost everything split, for loops, os, pathlib etc. and nothing is working for me and secondly is there a way to make the pictures appear in the pixmap when I press on their names in the QListWidget bc I have read all the documentations and I can't find anything (sorry for the long explanation).

Here is the code:

```
import sys
import os
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QDialog,
   QApplication, QWidget, QStackedWidget,
   QFileDialog,
   QLabel, QPushButton, QListWidget,
   QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout,
)
from PIL import Image
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap




class PhotoEditor(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(PhotoEditor, self).__init__()
        loadUi("photoeditor.ui", self)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.bfiles)

    def bfiles(self):
        mained = MainEditor()
        widget1.addWidget(mained)
        widget1.setCurrentIndex(widget1.currentIndex() + 1)
        




class MainEditor(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainEditor, self).__init__()
        loadUi("maineditor.ui", self)
        self.importbtn.clicked.connect(self.importer)

        
    def importer(self):
        fname = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self , 'Open File', 'C:', 'PNG Files (*.png);;JPEG Files (*.jpg)')
        index = (os.path.basename(fname))
        self.label_2.setPixmap(self.pixmap)
        self.piclist.addItem(index)
    
    
#main
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
pht = PhotoEditor()
edt = MainEditor()
widget1 = QStackedWidget()
widget1.addWidget(pht)
widget1.setFixedHeight(800)
widget1.setFixedWidth(1200)
widget1.show()
try:
   sys.exit(app.exec())
except:
   print("Exiting")
```

I have made two ui in the Qtdesigner you should ignore the first one called "photoeditor.ui"
and focus on the one in the second class called "maineditor.ui"

Here it is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>Dialog</class>
 <widget class="QDialog" name="Dialog">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>1200</width>
    <height>800</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Dialog</string>
  </property>
  <property name="styleSheet">
   <string notr="true">QWidget#Dialog{
background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);}</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="Line" name="line">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>29</y>
     <width>1201</width>
     <height>16</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="styleSheet">
    <string notr="true">font: 14pt &quot;MS Shell Dlg 2&quot;;</string>
   </property>
   <property name="orientation">
    <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QGraphicsView" name="graphicsView">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>1211</width>
     <height>41</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="styleSheet">
    <string notr="true">background-color: rgb(43, 43, 43);</string>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="Line" name="line_2">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>100</x>
     <y>-20</y>
     <width>16</width>
     <height>61</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="styleSheet">
    <string notr="true">color:rgb(0, 0, 0)</string>
   </property>
   <property name="orientation">
    <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QListWidget" name="piclist">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>20</x>
     <y>80</y>
     <width>141</width>
     <height>701</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="styleSheet">
    <string notr="true">background-color: rgb(43, 43, 43);</string>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>20</x>
     <y>50</y>
     <width>141</width>
     <height>21</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="styleSheet">
    <string notr="true">font: 12pt &quot;MS Shell Dlg 2&quot;;
background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
color: rgb(255, 255, 255);</string>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string>        Pictures</string>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QPushButton" name="importbtn">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>20</x>
     <y>10</y>
     <width>75</width>
     <height>21</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="styleSheet">
    <string notr="true">background-color: rgb(43, 43, 43);
font: 9pt &quot;MS Shell Dlg 2&quot;;
color:rgb(255, 255, 255)</string>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string>Import</string>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="Line" name="line_3">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>1090</x>
     <y>-20</y>
     <width>16</width>
     <height>61</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="styleSheet">
    <string notr="true">color:rgb(0, 0, 0)</string>
   </property>
   <property name="orientation">
    <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QPushButton" name="savebtn">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>1110</x>
     <y>10</y>
     <width>75</width>
     <height>21</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="styleSheet">
    <string notr="true">background-color: rgb(43, 43, 43);
font: 9pt &quot;MS Shell Dlg 2&quot;;
color:rgb(255, 255, 255)</string>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string>Save</string>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QPushButton" name="leftbtn">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>130</x>
     <y>10</y>
     <width>75</width>
     <height>21</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="styleSheet">
    <string notr="true">background-color: rgb(43, 43, 43);
font: 9pt &quot;MS Shell Dlg 2&quot;;
color:rgb(255, 255, 255)</string>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string>Left</string>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QPushButton" name="rightbtn">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>220</x>
     <y>10</y>
     <width>75</width>
     <height>21</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="styleSheet">
    <string notr="true">background-color: rgb(43, 43, 43);
font: 9pt &quot;MS Shell Dlg 2&quot;;
color:rgb(255, 255, 255)</string>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string>Right</string>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QPushButton" name="mirrorbtn">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>310</x>
     <y>10</y>
     <width>75</width>
     <height>21</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="styleSheet">
    <string notr="true">background-color: rgb(43, 43, 43);
font: 9pt &quot;MS Shell Dlg 2&quot;;
color:rgb(255, 255, 255)</string>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string>Mirror</string>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QPushButton" name="sharpbtn">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>400</x>
     <y>10</y>
     <width>75</width>
     <height>21</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="styleSheet">
    <string notr="true">background-color: rgb(43, 43, 43);
font: 9pt &quot;MS Shell Dlg 2&quot;;
color:rgb(255, 255, 255)</string>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string>Sharpness</string>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QPushButton" name="bwbtn">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>490</x>
     <y>10</y>
     <width>75</width>
     <height>21</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="styleSheet">
    <string notr="true">background-color: rgb(43, 43, 43);
font: 9pt &quot;MS Shell Dlg 2&quot;;
color:rgb(255, 255, 255)</string>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string>B&amp;W</string>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QLabel" name="label_2">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>186</x>
     <y>62</y>
     <width>991</width>
     <height>721</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="styleSheet">
    <string notr="true">background-color: rgb(43, 43, 43);</string>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string/>
   </property>
   <property name="scaledContents">
    <bool>true</bool>
   </property>
   <property name="alignment">
    <set>Qt::AlignCenter</set>
   </property>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Comment: First of all, please remember that you should only ask *one* question per post. Then, almost all static functions of QDialog (except for the directory functions) always return a tuple containing the path and the selected filter, so you either use `fname[0]` or assign a further variable (`fname, filter = QFileDialog..`). Then, you shall always check if the file string is not empty (which happens if the user cancels the dialog). Finally, I strongly suggest you to completely ignore that "Code first with Hala" tutorial, as it is known to provide **a lot** of terrible suggestions and bad practices.

Comment: @musicamante This was a premade code that was given to me from a team I am working with. Obviously there are things wrong with it I am in no position of knowing whether or not they used a tutorial or not. Now as of the code part the fname variable will return a tuple but that is also the problem since it is a tuple I can't split which is what I would usually do I have changed the index function to ```index = (os.path.basename(fname[0]))``` however I get another error
    self.label_2.setPixmap(self.pixmap)
AttributeError: 'MainEditor' object has no attribute 'pixmap'

Comment: That's clearly because there's no `self.pixmap` attribute, you have to create it from the path you get from the dialog. Then tell that team that the code above has **a lot** of serious issues, and they should not follow such bad practices, like adding QDialogs to a QStackedWidget, accessing a global variable like that, using a `try/except` without the exception type, setting fixed sizes without considering DPI and font scaling, not using layout managers, etc... All things that that tutorial *wrongly* suggests. If they learned PyQt and python from that, they should learn lots of things again.

Comment: @musicamante I fixed it so I would like to thank you for that. I talked to them and they said that what's the problem it works right ?. That's not the point though you are completely right. Even though some things may work right it doesn't mean that they are correct. The best example I could give is music just because d sharp and e flat sound the same that doesn't mean that they can be used either way. The point is that programming must have a correct flow like putting classes and imports on top etc. etc.

Comment: Yes, you're correct, and your example perfectly fits: if you write music using d sharps instead of e flats, the musician will [probably] play them right anyway, but why put them in such a pain? (besides, in some contexts, they are also *not* the same note) On the other hand, they *believe* that it works, but they will soon find out that the issues they're so *recklessly* underestimating *will* cause problems. Some examples: if you press the Esc key the UI disappears (due to the usage of QDialog); if the user has font scaling, the text might become unreadable (lack of layout managers);

Comment: then, continuously adding widgets to the stack is not only pointless, but also wrong. A stacked widget works like a tab widget (without a tab bar), "pages" are supposed to be *reused*. On the long run, the program will have hundreds of widgets that have been only used once, increasing memory usage pointlessly ("it works", but *very badly*). They are behaving just like the author of that awful tutorial: they don't take responsibility of their actions and don't consider consequences. That's just *bad* and irresponsible programming, I strongly hope they don't do that as a job with that mentality.